# How to drop empty columns in CSV with Python Pandas to fix error on expected values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I get an error when reading a CSV because it expects 11 values but finds 13. I found the issue is extra ",," at the end of the file. These don't correspond to any headers.

I tried using `usecols` to drop the empty values, but it seems that it still drops the record instead of just dropping those extra columns. Am I doing something wrong?

```py
dataFrame = pd.read_csv(inFile, engine='python', error_bad_lines=False, usecols=[*range(0,10)])
```

Comment: What version of pandas are you using?

Comment: use : `import pandas as pd ; pd.__version__` to print the version.

Comment: The version is pandas 1.1.2

Comment: I suppose I could drop the headers, then drop the empty columns, then re-add the headers. I'm not sure if it will work and it would be clunky, but I guess it would keep me moving.

Comment: So my previous comment doesn't seem to work since I would have to add extra commas. I guess my new approach will be to just read the file line by line, count the commas, then delete the excess commas at the end. I'm sure the performance will be slow and require more code, but I can't find anything like this in pandas.